# How do I tell systemd to start isc-dhcp-server after slapd?

Tags: 22.04, systemd, openldap, dhcpd

I have installed `isc-dhcp-server-ldap` and keep my DHCP configuration in OpenLDAP. This works perfectly.

However, when I reboot my server, `isc-dhcp-server` is not started:

```
s-hrt1# systemctl --failed
  UNIT                        LOAD   ACTIVE SUB    DESCRIPTION
● isc-dhcp-server.service     loaded failed failed ISC DHCP IPv4 server
● systemd-random-seed.service loaded failed failed Load/Save Random Seed
● systemd-rfkill.service      loaded failed failed Load/Save RF Kill Switch Status
● systemd-rfkill.socket       loaded failed failed Load/Save RF Kill Switch Status /dev/rfkill Watch
```

`journalctl -xeu isc-dhcp-server` reveals messages like the following:

```
Jun 20 06:07:36 s-hrt1 dhcpd[703]: Cannot set LDAP TLS crl check option: Can't contact LDAP server
```

If I manually restart `isc-dhcp-server` with `systemctl restart` it comes up with no problem.

I assume that `slapd`, the OpenLDAP server, is not ready when `isc-dhcp-server` starts. How do I tell `systemd` to wait for `slapd` before starting `isc-dhcp-server`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.unit.html#Requires=

The documentation says that if you want to control the order you have to use a combination of `Requires` with `Before/After`.

I would assume it's something like this:

````
[Unit]
Description=Start isc-dhcp-server
Requires=slapd.service
After=slapd.service```
````

Comment: Thanks, I’ll try that out later.

Comment: Sorry for the delay. Yes, that solved the problem for me. Thank you.